# How do I know if user press f5 or not to proccess something

Tags: asp.net, wcf, concurrency

I have WCF service to handle requests to render reports from rdlc files.

My issue:
A user prints a report, then when processing is in the middle, the user presses F5 to refresh.

As the result, we have two possible outcomes:

1. User reprints the report when processing of the previous report is still running.
2. User reprints the report when processing of the previous report is done.

With the two above scenarios, how can I detect which one applies?

Comment: Is the report printed client-side (eg by serving a Pdf with PrintMe() javascript) or server-side?

Comment: The report is rendered by WCF service and it's on server

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally you need a way to synchronise between requests. This isn't initially possible as none of your service instances have a reference to each other.

What you can do is [replace the default dependency resolver with your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh323725%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This will give you control over how your service instances are -er- instantiated.

You've then got a couple of options

- Have the whole service be a singleton. You could use private members to synchronise state. The downside to this approach is that your whole service needs to be thread-safe.
- Have multiple service instances as now, but give all of them a reference to a singleton which can be used for synchronising.

So your print method would look something like (pseudo):

```
public ReturnType PrintReport(ReportId, UserId) {
    If This.SyncObject.ReportRunning(ReportId, UserId) {
        //Whatever you want - throw an exception? Wait for running report to finish?
    }
    This.SyncObject.AddReport(ReportId, UserId)
    //Process as usual
    This.SyncObject.RemoveReport(ReportId, UserId)
}
```

obviously you'd need to make sure that reports don't get "stuck" in the syncobject if exceptions are thrown during printing/etc...

Comment: If I'm in your way, when user A render report, user B must waiting or not?(correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: It depends. I didn't put user-specific code in but it would be trivial to do so. Just make the `SyncObject` keep track of a `UserId` as well...